# How can I divide into columns the summarize() funtion with tidyverse?

Tags: r, dplyr, summarize

I am struggling with the `tidyverse` package. I'm using the `mpg` dataset from R to display the issue that I'm facing (ignore if the relationships are not relevant, it is just for the sake of explaining my problem).

What I'm trying to do is to obtain the average "displ" grouped by manufacturer and year AND at the same time (and this is what I can't figure out), have several columns for each of the fuel types variable (i.e.: a column for the mean of diesel, a column for the mean of petrol, etc.).

This is the first part of the code and I'm new to R so I really don't know what do I need to add...

```
mpg %>%
  group_by(manufacturer, year) %>%
  summarize(Mean. = mean(c(displ)))

# A tibble: 30 × 3
# Groups:   manufacturer [15]
   manufacturer  year Mean.
   <chr>        <int> <dbl>
 1 audi          1999  2.36
 2 audi          2008  2.73
 3 chevrolet     1999  4.97
 4 chevrolet     2008  5.12
 5 dodge         1999  4.32
 6 dodge         2008  4.42
 7 ford          1999  4.45
 8 ford          2008  4.66
 9 honda         1999  1.6 
10 honda         2008  1.85
# … with 20 more rows
```

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: I don't want to take means for different variables but instead for one variable (displ) divide it into the several values of the fl variable. I hope I explained myself a bit better.

Comment: Can you update your post with the expected output that you are looking for the `mpg` dataset?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps, we need to reshape into 'wide'

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
mpg %>% 
   select(manufacturer, year, fl, displ) %>%
   pivot_wider(names_from = fl, values_from = displ, values_fn = mean)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 30 x 7
   manufacturer  year     p     r     e     d     c
   <chr>        <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 audi          1999  2.36 NA    NA     NA    NA  
 2 audi          2008  2.73 NA    NA     NA    NA  
 3 chevrolet     2008  6.47  4.49  5.3   NA    NA  
 4 chevrolet     1999  5.7   4.22 NA      6.5  NA  
 5 dodge         1999 NA     4.32 NA     NA    NA  
 6 dodge         2008 NA     4.42  4.42  NA    NA  
 7 ford          1999 NA     4.45 NA     NA    NA  
 8 ford          2008  5.4   4.58 NA     NA    NA  
 9 honda         1999  1.6   1.6  NA     NA    NA  
10 honda         2008  2     1.8  NA     NA     1.8
# … with 20 more rows
```